# What is the name of this mechanism in the genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

In each evolution generation, a new population is constructed by the genetic operators.

In my implementation, I combine the new population and the old population together, and then sort all of them by the fitness. Among them, the top 100 ranked genomes are returned as the population for the next evolution generation (Suppose the population consists of 100 genomes).

This mechanism works well in my implementation. So, what is the name of this mechanism? I have read about it but forget its name. Could anyone tell me and give some references?

Comment: Maybe you mean "elitism"? Usually that means that you carry to top ranked individuals from the old population unaltered to the next evolution generation in addition to individuals from the new generation - so it is not 100 % identical to your mechanism.

Comment: You should ask this question here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ . Their banner: Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development. It's 100% free, no registration required.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. I also thought whether it can be called  a elitism mechanism. However, when I checked the detailed definition, I think it is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a form of **crowding**. For example, [NSGA-II](http://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/Deb_NSGA-II.pdf) (a multi-objective GA) uses a crowding mechanism more or less identical to the one you described.

But it's a form of elitism too.

Answer (score 0):

It's elitism - see info at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm#Elitism)

Elitism usually leads quicker to a better solution as "good" solutions are not lost. However in certain solution spaces you may not reach the global optimum. In some of my GA's I used a larger population instead of elitism to carry over good gens. Also reinitialization (when genoms start to become similar) can help to find the gloabl optimum. You may give it a try.